# Does $f$ have at the point $x=4$ local extreme?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(x)=1-(x-4)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^{3}+o((x-4)^{3})$ where $x \rightarrow 4$. 
> Does $f$ have at the point $x=4$ local extreme?

I know that when $f$ is twice differentiable, $f''$ is continuous, $f'(x_{0})=0$:
(1) $f''(x)>0 \Rightarrow f$ has a local minimum in $x_{0}$

(1) $f''(x)<0 \Rightarrow f$ has a local maximum in $x_{0}$
If I consider $$g(x)=1-(x-4)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(x-4)^{3}$$ then I have $$g'(4)=0$$ and $$g''(4)=-2$$That is why $g$ has a local maxiumum in $x_{0}=4$. 
$f(x)=g(x)+o((x-4)^{3})$ and $o((x-4)^{3}) \rightarrow 0$ so I think I can say that $f,g$ has extremes in the same points. 
  However I don't know if I'm right, and if so how can it be professionally justified?

Comment: can't $o((x-4)^3)$ be $x^2$ for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$f(x)=1-(x-4)^2\left(1-{1\over2}(x-4)+o(x-4)\right)\qquad(x\to4)\ .$$
Since
$$\lim_{x\to4}\left(-{1\over2}(x-4)+o(x-4)\right)=0$$
we can conclude that
$$ f(x)<1-{1\over2}(x-4)^2\qquad\left(0<|x-4|<\epsilon\right)$$
for some $\epsilon>0$. As $f(4)=1$ it follows that $f$ has a strict local maximum at $x=4$.